# Time prediction model

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to make a model that predicts how long time a project will take. The current model shows how long it is ***likely*** to take. But I want to make a model how ***long*** it will take. This can be made by adding all previous numbers until 100% percentage is reached. The result should be something like a S-curve. That is, instead of decreasing halfway, I want it to increase until it reaches 100%.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mc2d)
library(scales)
n=1000

planing=rpert(n, min=30, mode=40, max=70, shape=0)
marketing=rpert(n, min=40, mode=60, max=120, shape=30)
hirepeople=rpert(n, min=25, mode=40, max=70, shape=30)

totallength=planing + marketing + hirepeople

p <- ggplot(data.frame(totallength), aes(x = totallength))  
p <- p + geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), color = "black", fill = "steelblue", 
                        binwidth = 5)
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
p <- p + xlab("Days") + ylab("Percentage")
p <- p + theme_bw() 
print(p)
```

Comment: You should read some introduction manual about probability and statistics and learn the difference between PDF and CDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `ecdf` statistics for [`geom_histogram`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html). This will sum all percentages and will result in what you are looking for.

```
qplot(totallength, stat = "ecdf", geom = "step")
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get percentage (25%, 50% and so on) instead of 0.25, 0.50 on y-axis

Answer (score 0):

adding something like  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),labels = percent_format()) should add the percentage.